# Problem with й (\cyrishrt) in LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex

Initially I've asked a different question, but digging up I've found a true reason.

The problem occurs when Cyrillic letter й is used with maths in another font in the same paragraph. Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\begin{document}
й $xy$
\end{document}
```

The compilation stops and the error is following:

```
error: ...s/MiKTeX 2.9
/tex/luatex/luaotfload/otfl-node-inj.lua:225: attempt to index local 'tm' (a nil
value)
.
\newpage ...k \@nobreakfalse \everypar {}\fi \par
                                              \vfil \penalty -\@M
l.6 \end{document}
```

When they are in different paragraphs e.g. the document body is

```
\begin{document}
й 

$xy$
\end{document}
```

then there is no problem. Also there is no problem as well if I use the same math font e.g. with

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
```

But still the compilation stops if I use a symbol from a different font (e.g. \Box from amssymb).

UPD: I get the same problem with other accented letters, not only Cyrillic: à, ѓ, ё, ї, ќ, ў etc, except i.

UPD2: Happens only with Cambria.

Comment: It doesn't happen to me, but I don't have Cambria and so I've used a different font. Does it happen with another font than Cambria to you?

Comment: Thanks for pointing. It happens only with Cambria indeed.

Comment: luaotfload bug, report it.

Comment: I have the Cambria font, and I don't experience the problem you're reporting. My setup: MacOSX Lion 10.7.2, MacTeX2011 with all the latest patches, Microsoft's Cambria .ttf files with file date 1 June 2010.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation. Also, please remove "(Solved)" from the question title.

Comment: As detailed in the answer, this is an issue with a local copy of a font. I'm therefore marking 'too localized'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a problem with my Cambria font installation. In the Windows/Fonts folder, there were Cambria Italic.ttf, Cambria Bold.ttf, Cambria Bold Italic.ttf containing the corresponding fonts and Cambria.ttc containing both Cambria Regular and Cambria Math. So with bold and italic there was no problem, but somehow using regular lead to a problem when LuaLaTeX used Cambria Regular from Cambria.ttc. When I copied Cambria.ttf from Vista installation DVD and deleted luatex-cache folder, the problem had gone.